# Selecting GPU debug type for c# windows store app

Tags: debugging, windows-store-apps, windows-rt, c++-amp

I have a solution with a C# XAML windows store app and a WinRT component which exposes C++ AMP code. A reference from app to component is set up and I can run this and with mixed mode debugging I can step into the win rt component.

I can however not select the "debugger type" of "gpu only", which launches debugging with the sotware emulation gpu debugger. I can select mixed mode and debug both the c# app and the c++ rt component, but gpu is not available, so I can't step into the actual parallel_for_each code block of the kernel.

If I use a C++ XAML windows store app as the host, I can easily enough select "gpu only" as the debugger type.

One solution is to build and launch the solution (C# app+C++ component) without debugging and then manually go under debug/attach to process and find my running process, select gpu degbugger and attach. That actually works, as long as I manually ensure to use the correct accelerator.

Since I can do this debuging in a roundabout way by manually attaching, it seems obvious it should be able to work by the normal F5 run and debug, which essentially does the same thing in an easier way.

I would be very interested in hearing about how this could be setup to work as usual and what the reason for my difficulties is.

Nb. I had a post about this with a different wording and tags because I didn't really understand the problem and workarounds then. I deleted that post and wrote this on instead.

Comment: In your solution's configuration manager, are all the projects set to debug mode?

Comment: Yes, they are. I can also debug into the c++ rt component while launching from c# app, just not set the default debugger to GPU. By manually attaching the debugger I can select GPU and then I can step into the C++AMP kernel with no problems.